# Erro com nodejs/autenticação/middleware

Tags: node.js

Estou com um problema ao realizar o login no blog, o problema é: ao tentar realizar o login na primeira vez com um usuário 0 (sem ser admin) ele fica carregando a página e não vai para lugar nenhum, mas após eu clicar em outra guia ou recarregar a página é efetuado o login, somente acontece se eu fizer isso, se eu tentar logar com um usuario admin (1) ele efetua normalmente o acesso, eu deslogando e tentando logar novamente no usuário 0 ele funciona corretamente. Creio que seja um problema com o middleware mas não consegui encontrar essa falha na autenticação

Um trecho do código de autenticação:

```
module.exports = {
    pAdmin: function(req, res, next){

        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next();
        }

        req.flash("error_msg", "Você precisa ser um professor")
        res.redirect("/")

    }

}
```

Obs: sou novato ainda.

Alguem sabe me informar oque pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: 1: como que está sendo feito o login?Normalmente geramos um token no cadastro e no login
2: Você está passando o token corretamente? headers:{"Authentication":" codigo do token "}
3: Está usando oq para testa a sua API? Insomnia?

Comment: Estou utilizando o passport-locals, sou novato, aparentemente está tudo OK com o código, notei que o usuário era logado mas não seguia em frente, como se faltasse um next(), fiz uma gambiarra com o javascript onde eu redireciono ele para a pagina inicial, assim ele "forca" o next(), eu creio que para algo inicial ele deve estar funcionando, mas sei também que não é o correto a se fazer.

Comment: JavaScript, mas você está usando o react-native, reactjs ou outros como front? Normalmente não fazemos nada dentro do middleware.

Comment: To usando o Handlebars